# JS function stops at 100 for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript

I am building a game stats calculator and I have come across a strange problem. I have 4 stats and i have a pool of starting points to distribute across those 4 stats. I use buttons to add stat points but I also use buttons to remove stat points in case of an error. Thanks to help from here, I managed to do the initial logic of adding skill points by decrementing the remaining pool and while incrementing the stat i am clicking. That works fine. However, when i introduced the removing of point functions they behave strange. I know it's a math/logical problem but i can't solve it. For some reason, once i assign 100 stat points to any of the 4 stats, the remove functions stop meeting the If conditions.

Here is how I do it:

```
// stats
const str = document.getElementsByName('str');
const dex = document.getElementsByName("dex");
const vit = document.getElementsByName("vit");
const ene = document.getElementsByName("ene");
const statsRemaining = document.getElementsByName("statsRemaining");
// Add stats
function addStr() {
  if (statsRemaining[0].value > 0) {
    str[0].value++;
    statsRemaining[0].value--;
  }
}

function addDex() {
  if (statsRemaining[0].value > 0) {
    ++dex[0].value;
    --statsRemaining[0].value;
  }
}

function addVit() {
  if (statsRemaining[0].value > 0) {
    vit[0].value++;
    statsRemaining[0].value--;
  }
}

function addEne() {
  if (statsRemaining[0].value > 0) {
    ene[0].value++;
    statsRemaining[0].value--;
  }
}
// Remove stats
function removeStr() {
  if (str[0].value > str[0].defaultValue) {
    str[0].value--;
    statsRemaining[0].value++;
  }
}

function removeDex() {
  if (dex[0].value > dex[0].defaultValue) {
    dex[0].value--;
    statsRemaining[0].value++;
  }
}

function removeVit() {
  if (vit[0].value > vit[0].defaultValue) {
    vit[0].value--;
    statsRemaining[0].value++;
  }
}

function removeEne() {
  if (ene[0].value > ene[0].defaultValue) {
    ene[0].value--;
    statsRemaining[0].value++;
  }
}

function resetStats() {
  str[0].value = str[0].defaultValue;
  dex[0].value = dex[0].defaultValue;
  vit[0].value = vit[0].defaultValue;
  ene[0].value = ene[0].defaultValue;
  statsRemaining[0].value = statsRemaining[0].defaultValue;
}
```

You can see it in action live where i've implemented it - https://www.diablo-2.net/character-planner/?class=Necromancer&clevel=99#character-stats. Try assigning more than 100 stats on each 4 and the removing stops working.
I have a JS fiddle with a more modest implementation which is more suited for here but there i even get different results with the same code! - the "Energy" stat there does not have any issues!
https://jsfiddle.net/Skarsburning/1cjzoxfb/28/

Appreciate help with solving this logical/math problem.

Comment: `value` is a string so the comparisons are going to be off.

Comment: what @epascarello said above. You are comparing strings not numbers. so once you go over 100 you compare if `"100" > "25"` which is `false`. Here a version that turns them to numbers before the comparisons https://jsfiddle.net/0tmzs87c/ although you should do that wherever you do math

Comment: Agreed on the reason, what I couldn't work out is why the minus buttons do work a little bit if you add +10 a few times. What is the logic on "number as string" comparisons in JavaScript? Just something I have never really given any thought to as I just default to doing numeric comparisons! (probably something I should know at this point in my career :-P)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Both strings, it's lexicographic ordering.  If one of the elements is a number and the other can be parsed into a number, they will be compared as numbers.  If one is a non-number string and the other is a number, it will be false.

Comment: Gabriele Petrioli ! That's absolutelly incredible..... I would have never though of using the + operator in front. I am so grateful. I've banged my head on this for hours (i need to get back to the JS starting courses as it seems). I am so happy and i love Stackoverflow. I want to award you the Answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you're doing it is definitely not D.R.Y. but to fix your issue, you just have to make sure you comparing the numerical values (in numbers) over the string values (in # of characters).

So `statsRemaining[0].value` should be `Number(statsRemaining[0].value)`

***EDIT***

I've attached a better way to do what you're looking for that's infinitely-extensible (you don't have to add more stats states for more attributes, etc.)

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/5xvzmnc6/42/

```js
// stats
const str = document.getElementsByName('str');
const dex = document.getElementsByName("dex");
const vit = document.getElementsByName("vit");
const ene = document.getElementsByName("ene");
const statsRemaining = document.getElementsByName("statsRemaining");

function statDist(elem, shouldAdd)
{
 var selected = elem.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("stat")[0];
  
  if (shouldAdd && Number(statsRemaining[0].value) > 0)
   {
     selected.value++
      statsRemaining[0].value--;
    } else if (!shouldAdd && Number(selected.value) > 0)
    {
     statsRemaining[0].value++;
      selected.value--;
    } else 
    {
     alert("No more skill points!");
    }
}

function resetStats() {
  str[0].value = str[0].defaultValue;
  dex[0].value = dex[0].defaultValue;
  vit[0].value = vit[0].defaultValue;
  ene[0].value = ene[0].defaultValue;
  statsRemaining[0].value = statsRemaining[0].defaultValue;
}
```

```html
<div class="stat-card">
<p>Strength</p>
        <input class="stat" type="number" value="85" name="str" id="str" readonly /><span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,true)">+</span>  <span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,false)">-</span>
</div>

<div class="stat-card">
<p>Dexterity</p>
        <input class="stat" type="number" value="25" name="dex" id="dex" readonly /><span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,true)">+</span>  <span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,false)">-</span>
</div>

<div class="stat-card">
<p>Vitality</p>
        <input class="stat" type="number" value="15" name="vit" id="vit" readonly /><span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,true)">+</span>  <span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,false)">-</span>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-card">
<p>Energy</p>
        <input class="stat" type="number" value="10" name="ene" id="ene" readonly /><span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,true)">+</span>  <span style="font-size: 26px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="statDist(this,false)">-</span>
        </div>
        <br><br>
<p>Stat points remaining: <input style="width: 42px;" type="number" name="statsRemaining" value="10" readonly /></p><br>
<input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset Stats" onclick="resetStats()" />
```

This is done in vanilla JS, and if you use jQuery you don't have to add classes to and `<div>`s to the stats to make targeting *way* easier.

Here is the vanilla JS way:

1. Create a `<div>` element for each stat. Add classname 'stat' so you can target the parent `<div>` with js and then find the classname 'stat' that's a child of it.
2. The onclick sends to the same function, instead of separate functions. You use `this` so the function knows *which* `this` is talking, and you use a boolean value for whether or not it should be adding or subtracting. So If you add `onclick="statDist(this,true)"`, that's telling the function '*this* button called the function, so find it's parent div. Grab the input class and work with that.' Then, the next parameter is the boolean, which tells the function whether or not you're trying to *add* or subtract a point.
3. Inside of the function you have to main states: `shouldAdd` and `!shouldAdd`. So it's basically two functions in one.
4. The else statement fires if either run out of points. You can obviously build upon it if you want.

Comment: Hey Joel, i like how you want to make it as a function and reduce the iterations of code i need to write to achieve this functionality but your i tried adapting your example to my real life scenario and i ran into issues such as the 10 bulk add/remove and most of all the current suggestion allows for stats to go under the default value. For now, adding + operator in front of my variables solved it the easiest.

Comment: You can easily use the same code to get the value to add a conditional as well.

Comment: Where were you adding the bulk add options? Do you have a code example you can link to?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because the greater than/less than comparisons inside of every one of your functions are comparing a string value with another string value. The values of text input elements from the DOM are strings. When you compare two strings in JavaScript, it uses "lexicographical" comparison (see [here](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) for how that works if you're curious). In short, the string "100" is not greater than the string "85" in JavaScript. The problem is very easy to solve - just cast the input string values to numbers by calling Number() on them. For example:

```
function removeStr() {
  const strInput = str[0];
  const remainingDisplay = statsRemaining[0];
  let str = Number(strInput .value);
  let initialStr = Number(strInput.defaultValue);
  let statsRemaining = Number(remainingDisplay.value)
  if (str > initialStr) {
    strInput.value = str - 1;
    remainingDisplay .value = statsRemaining - 1;
  }
}
```

Another tip: you could avoid all those array [0] positions by assigning each input element an id and then using document.getElementById('inputId') instead of using getElementsByName.

Answer (score -1):

Note : Only did this for first "str" named element.

Well I tried this simple thing on your code at fiddle and it worked.

```
function removeStr() {
  console.log("Def:"+str[0].defaultValue);
  console.log("val:"+str[0].value);
    if (parseInt(str[0].value) > parseInt(str[0].defaultValue)) { **-> HERE**

    str[0].value--;
  statsRemaining[0].value++;
  }
}
```

Check it out here.

[image]

As shown above I incremented value to 100 than I subtracted to below 100.